# How to mock DbContext using moq and nunit

Tags: c#, nunit, moq

Please i am trying to mock a DbContext and write a test, from my test the error seems to come from the mocking of the DbContext. maybe the way i set it up isn't correct. can anyone spot the error or a better way of setting it up? Thanks

Test and Setup : upVoteControllerTest.cs

```
[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.AddProfile<MapperInitilizer>();
    });
    _realMapper = new Mapper(config);
    _upvotes = new Mock<IRepository<Upvote>>();
    _unitOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
    _unitOfWork.SetupGet(work => work.Upvotes).Returns(_upvotes.Object);
    _logger = new Mock<ILogger<UpvoteController>>();
    _mapper = new Mock<IMapper>();
    _context = new Mock<ApplicationDbContext>();
    _upvoteController = new UpvoteController(_context.Object, _mapper.Object,_unitOfWork.Object, _logger.Object);
    upvote_one = new Upvote()
    {
        Id = 1,
        UserId = "43434343434",
        TopicId = 1
    };
  
    upvote_two = new Upvote()
    {
        Id = 2,
        UserId = "65664535",
        TopicId = 2
    };

    user_one = new User()
    {
        Id = "43434343434",
        FirstName = "john",
        LastName = "doe",
        Email = "john@gmail.com",
        Photo = "hgghghg",
        PhoneNumber = "fgfffgfg"
    };

    List<User> expectedResult = new List<User> {user_one};
    var repo = new UserTestRepository();
}




[Test]
    public void GetAllUpVotes_SendRequest_ReturnListOfUpVotes()
    {
        List<Upvote> expectedResult = new List<Upvote> {upvote_one, upvote_two};
        var repo = new UpvoteTestRepository(expectedResult);
        var unitOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
        unitOfWork.SetupGet(work => work.Upvotes).Returns(repo);
        _upvoteController.GetUpvotes().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        
        Assert.IsNotEmpty(repo.Source);
        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expectedResult, repo.GetAll().GetAwaiter().GetResult());
    }
```

UpvoteController:

```
public UpvoteController(ApplicationDbContext context, IMapper mapper, 
            IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, ILogger<UpvoteController> logger)
        {
            _context = context;
            _mapper = mapper;
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        // GET: api/Upvote
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetUpvotes()
        {
            try
            {
                var upvotes = await _unitOfWork.Upvotes.GetAll();
                var results = _mapper.Map<IList<UpvoteDTO>>(upvotes);
                return Ok(results);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.LogError(e, $"Something went wrong in the {nameof(GetUpvotes)}");
                return StatusCode(500, "Internal server error");
            }
        }
```

UpvoteTestRepository:

```
public class UpvoteTestRepository : IRepository<Upvote>
{
    public IList<Upvote> Source;

    public UpvoteTestRepository(IList<Upvote> source)
    {
        Source = source;
    }

    public Task<Upvote> Get(Expression<Func<Upvote, bool>> expression, 
        Func<IQueryable<Upvote>, IIncludableQueryable<Upvote, object>> include = null)
    {
        
        IQueryable<Upvote> query = Source.AsQueryable();
        return Task.FromResult(query.FirstOrDefault(expression));
    }

    public Task<IList<Upvote>> GetAll(Expression<Func<Upvote, bool>> expression = null, Func<IQueryable<Upvote>, IOrderedQueryable<Upvote>> orderBy = null, Func<IQueryable<Upvote>, IIncludableQueryable<Upvote, object>> include = null, Expression<Func<Upvote, bool>> cat = null,
        int limit = 0)
    {
        
        return Task.FromResult(Source);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
System.ArgumentException : Can not instantiate proxy of class: dotnetapp.Data.ApplicationDbContext.
    Could not find a parameterless constructor. (Parameter 'constructorArguments')
    ----> System.MissingMethodException : Constructor on type 'Castle.Proxies.ApplicationDbContextProxy' not found.
    at Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator.CreateClassProxyInstance(Type proxyType, List`1 proxyArguments, Type classToProxy, Object[] constructorArguments)
at Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator.CreateClassProxy(Type classToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfacesToProxy, ProxyGenerationOptions options, Object[]
```

Comment: Mocking DbContext isn’t simple and most people will say you shouldn’t do that at all. There’s some pages online which will explain what parts need to be done but might not work for all cases and all mocking frameworks

Comment: Yeap as @SamiKuhmonen mentioned mocking `DbContext` is hard but mocking a db with `SqLite` is super easy.

Comment: i need to pass the _context to the UpvoteController in the test, so with the way my test is written i have to moq the dbContext. i'm new to testing

Comment: In this code it’s not used at all in the controller, is there something that it’s actually used? As @Eldar mentioned using SQLite (in-memory) database is simple and you can use the actual DbContext then. Other option is to have a layer on top of data access and you can mock it instead of DbContext

Answer (score 1):

You can use in-memory db. But that's not such a good decision, [there](https://jimmybogard.com/avoid-in-memory-databases-for-tests/) you can see why, but in general, if your app(db in general) is small it`s okay.

```
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>()
                      .UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
                      .Options;
var context = new MyDbContext(options);
context.Database.EnsureCreated();
```

In addition you can do it much better with [EF Effort](https://entityframework-effort.net/). Which also use in-memory db, but efficient way